# Run python Variable in Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to test some code and have created the following variable: [image]
data = numpy.array([[1, -1], [0, 1], [-1.5, -1]])

now, I want to test how this variable is printed by typing 'print(data)' in the terminal.
however, I receive error, saying name 'data' not defined.

Doesn't the python terminal recognize variables created in the code editor above?
I am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: When you start the Python interpreter, it doesn't automatically run code that you have open in your (unrelated) code editor. You can run `python -i myscript.py` to run your script *and* stay in the REPL.

Comment: You probably want to use the Debug Console.

Comment: Maybe also look into jupyter notebooks if you want a more interactive environment. In vs code can just create a new file with .ipynb (vs code will prompt to install the library if you don't have it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vscode **Terminal** uses the **Power Shell** built into windows. If you just type `python` in the terminal and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you get the same effect as running `python` in an external cmd window, it just opens the python interactive window and does not run the current python script.

**If you want to implement your idea, please follow the steps below.**

**code**

```py
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1,-1],[0,1],[-1.5,-1]])
```

**Steps**

- <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> open python interactive terminal

  [image]
- Select the code, use <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the code in the interactive terminal

  [image]
- Type `print(data)` to print out the data

  [image]

**Here is another way**

- Select the code, right click and select **Run Selection/Line in Interactive Window**

  [image]
- This will open an interactive window and run the selected code

  [image]
- Type `print(data)` in the box below the interactive window

  [image]
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run `print(data)`, and print out the data

  [image]

*Tips: The window opened by the second way supports IntelliSense*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define data in the python terminal separately, it won't find it from your code unless you run your code.

If you want to see how it will be printed in your terminal by itself then you can just define data the line before in the terminal and then print it.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> data = numpy.array([[1, -1], [0, 1], [-1.5, -1]])
>>> print(data)
[[ 1.  -1. ]
 [ 0.   1. ]
 [-1.5 -1. ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The terminal won't just recognize variables in the editor, you must execute the code in a python terminal. You can do this by selecting the code you want to execute then pressing command + shift + p and searching for Python: Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal

Answer (score 0):

The python terminal in VS Code is like you just running the `python` command in a normal terminal.

If you want an interactive prompt you need to run the file manually with the -i option like this.

```
python -i path/to/your/script/here
```